# Keycloak LDAP User Authentication not working

Tags: jboss, ldap, keycloak

I have configured OpenLDAP with my keycloak, so that user management is taken care by LDAP. I have successfully sync the users from LDAP and I can see the user details in my List of users in Keycloak.I am using master realm only.
But when I try to generate token giving admin-cli client it gives this error.
[image]

Even the Authorization code flow it doesn't work.Tried to log in via keycloak UI it gives Invalid Credentials.

How can we use LDAP users for authentication in Keycloak ?

Comment: what does the keycloak log say? there must be detailed error. Also , in your client is the Authorization enabled? Is it a public client?

Comment: This is admin-cli i am trying to generate the token.It doesnt require the client Secret..It just says that the user authentication failed...

Comment: The password is `password`.